# Multiples TOC for overlapping content

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a book typesetted in latex with about 30 stories. The stories conform 3 books with stories overlapping, this means story1 appears in book1 and book2, for example.

How can I generate a latex document containing 3 TOCs? each one pointing to the tales corresponding to each "sub book"?

I suspect that the solution should include a way to tell for each story (chapter) to which "sub book"(s) it belongs.

Answer (score 2):

Since no example is given, I'll try to provide an answer based on assumptions and `minitoc` package.

This uses `\part` as 'subbook' and `\parttoc` as macro to instruct `minitoc` to generate a local toc. The local toc title can be changed to by redefinition of the `\ptctitle` macro.

*Note*: The `minitoc` package is about 6 years old, as of writing just now and somehow unmaintained. An alternative might be the usage of `etoc` package.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{blindtext}%

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother


\let\standardptctitle\ptctitle%

\doparttoc

\renewcommand{\partname}{Book}

\begin{filecontents}{story1.tex}
\chapter{Story 1}%
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{story2.tex}
\chapter{Story 2}%
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{story3.tex}
\chapter{Story 3}%
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}

\part{Some Stories}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\ptctitle}{\standardptctitle~of \partname~\thepart}
\parttoc

\input{story1}
\input{story2}

\part{More Stories}
\parttoc
\input{story2}
\input{story3}

\part{Even More Stories}
\parttoc

\input{story3}
\input{story1}


\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version with `etoc` package

The `etoc` package provides an easy access to `\localtableofcontents` and is maintained. See [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) for more information.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoc}%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{blindtext}%

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

\let\StandardContentsName\contentsname


\renewcommand{\partname}{Book}

\begin{filecontents}{story1.tex}
\chapter{Story 1}%
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{story2.tex}
\chapter{Story 2}%
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{story3.tex}
\chapter{Story 3}%
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents% The whole document contents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\StandardContentsName~of \partname~\thepart}

\part{Some Stories}
\localtableofcontents

\input{story1}
\input{story2}

\part{More Stories}
\localtableofcontents
\input{story2}
\input{story3}

\part{Even More Stories}
\localtableofcontents

\input{story3}
\input{story1}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem I see with this solution is that stories are repeated inside the whole book. I don't want that. I want them to appear only once. Can this be achieve?

Comment: @JuanjoConti: * 3 books with stories overlapping, this means story1 appears in book1 and book2, for example.* This could be interpreted as a multiple appearance of the same story. Your question is somewhat not clear and there is no example given

Comment: @JuanjoConti I think I interpreted your question (which wasn't that clear:-) the way you intended "overlapping" to be understood. Let me know if not:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, it was probably meant that way you did it, but for me it was not clear initially.

Comment: I want the stories to be printed only once. Is that clear? :) Thanks a lot. Excuse my english.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\old@starttoc\@starttoc
\let\old@addcontentsline\addcontentsline
\def\@toc{toc}
\def\@alltoc{tocabc}
\def\@starttoc#1{%
\def\tmp{#1}%
\ifx\tmp\@toc\let\tmp\currenttoc\fi
\old@starttoc\tmp}
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
\def\tmp{#1}%
\ifx\tmp\@toc
\ifx\currenttoc\@alltoc
\old@addcontentsline{toca}{#2}{#3}%
\old@addcontentsline{tocb}{#2}{#3}%
\old@addcontentsline{tocc}{#2}{#3}%
\else
\old@addcontentsline{\currenttoc}{#2}{#3}%
\fi
\else
\old@addcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}%
\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\def\currenttoc{toca}\def\contentsname{story 1 contents}\tableofcontents
\def\currenttoc{tocb}\def\contentsname{story 2 contents}\tableofcontents
\def\currenttoc{tocc}\def\contentsname{story 3 contents}\tableofcontents


\def\currenttoc{tocabc}
\section{book, the first}

\def\currenttoc{toca}
\subsection{start}
red red blue yellow red red blue yellow
red red blue yellow red red blue yellow

\def\currenttoc{tocb}
\subsection{new start}
one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five 


\def\currenttoc{tocabc}
\section{book, the second}

\def\currenttoc{tocb}
\subsection{more numbers}
one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five 

\def\currenttoc{tocc}
\subsection{even newer start}
rome paris london 
rome paris london 
rome paris london 

\def\currenttoc{toca}
\subsection{return to colour}
black blue green black blue green black blue green 
black blue green black blue green black blue green 

\def\currenttoc{tocabc}
\section{book, the third}


\def\currenttoc{tocb}
\subsection{numbers again}
one two three four five one two three four five 
one two three four five one two three four five 

\end{document}
```

Comment: why the downvote?